# Latex subfloat the "subcaption" is one word in one line, how to make them together in only one line

Tags: latex

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0OsN.png) As the picture describes, the caption of the subfloat is not normal, I want them in one line.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \subfloat[Text GCN 1 layer]{
        \label{t-SNE-a}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tsne文档嵌入展示a.pdf}
    }
    \subfloat[HAN]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tsne文档嵌入展示b.pdf}
        \label{t-SNE-b}
    }
    \\
    \subfloat[“Text GCN 第二层”]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tsne文档嵌入展示c.pdf}
        \label{t-SNE-c}
    }
    \caption{t-SNE文档嵌入可视化}
    \label{t-SNE文档嵌入可视化}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `subfigure` environment of the package `subcaption`. This environment has the width of the subfigure as argument.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
      \label{t-SNE-a}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tsne文档嵌入展示a.pdf}
      \caption{First very very long caption!}
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
      \label{t-SNE-b}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tsne文档嵌入展示b.pdf}
      \caption{Second very very long caption!}
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
      \label{t-SNE-c}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tsne文档嵌入展示c.pdf}
      \caption{A third caption, just a bit longer than the others.}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{General caption}
   \label{t-SNE文档嵌入可视化}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```